# Проблема с арифметикой динамических переменных С++

Tags: c++, указатели

Пишу ради практики свой класс string, и нужно инициализировать динамическую переменную типа int ***strLen*** и столкнулся с проблемой, а конкретно непонятная работа инкремента:

```
//компилятор clang 
String::String(char* str){
    int* strLen = new int(0);
    std::cout << "_______\ncell:\t " << strLen << "\nvariable = \t" << *strLen << "\n_______\n";
    *strLen++;
    std::cout << "_______\ncell:\t " << strLen << "\nvariable = \t" << *strLen << "\n_______\n";

}
```

на выходе получается что увеличилось не значение, а адрес:

```
_______
cell:    0x19a7dea1960
variable =      0
_______
_______
cell:    0x19a7dea1964
variable =      -1414812757
_______
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Я честно говоря не понимаю почему так происходит, потому что как я думал, переменная со знаком указателя должна изменяться в значении, а не в адресе. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приоритеты операций...

```
int * p;

(*p)++   // Увеличение значения по адресу p, адрес неизменный

*p++;    // Разыменование, получение значения, увеличение значения адреса p
```

Comment: спасибо! честно говоря забыл вообще про это свойство.

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...